# change the text for link button when i click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

i wan t to change the text for link button when i click on it if it show make hide .

```js
 function Showtxt() {
             $("#LinkButton1").click();
             if ($("#LinkButton1").text("show") == true) {
                 $("#LinkButton1").text("hide")
             }
             else {
                 $("#LinkButton1").text("show")
             }

             }

         }
```

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="Showtxt();" Text="show"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is an extra `}` at the end and you should remove it.above code solves the issue

```
function Showtxt() {
            if ($("#LinkButton1").text() == 'show') {
                alert('up');
                $("#LinkButton1").text("hide")
            }
            else {
                alert('down');
                $("#LinkButton1").text("show")
            }
        }
```

but there is another problem,and that is `PostBack`,and it force the page to refresh and "hide" replace by "show" after `PostBack`.